# Angular2 & Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, angular2

Есть отдельные nodejs-приложения, запущенные в докере.
Есть отдельно работающие angular2-приложения (docker -> nginx). Связь между ними происходит с помощью ip & nginx-конфига.

Теперь вопрос: можно ли связать socket.io с nodejs-сервером который находится даже на другой машине (физически) ?

Я понимаю что есть много примеров работы Angular2 & Nodejs + Socket.io.
Однако они все работают на одной машине (в одном nodejs-приложении).
Можно ли подключить к nodejs-серверу клиента (находящиеся на разных машинах) с помощью socket.io ?

Comment: А как вы соединение с сокетом на клиенте настраиваете. Там же пишется его адрес, порт.

Comment: Да, согласен. Вот так: this.socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
Однако они находятся на одном компьютере. А будут ли они работать на разных компьютерах?

Comment: Чтобы nodejs-приложение на одном, а angular2 на другом

Comment: А какая разница) Адрес есть адрес, он будет стучаться туда, куда вы скажете. Главное чтобы права доступа к домену были, типа `allow-control-allow-origin`

Comment: Сейчас буду пробовать отпишусь. Спасибо за ответы

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос крайне прост? действительно можно работать с socket.io на различных машинах. Главное правильно прописать адрес и порт.
Пример:

```
this.socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
    this.socket.on('message', function(data){
        alert(data);
    }.bind(this));
```